# Java using scanner enter key pressed

Tags: java, input, console, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am programming using Java.
I am trying write code which can recognize if the user presses the enter key in a **console based program.**

How can I do this using java. I have been told that this can be done using either Scanner or, buffered input reader. I do not understand(or know how to use) buffered input reader.

I tried to do do this using scanner but after pressing enter twice the program terminates, and it doesn't work

```
    Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String enterkey = "Hola";
    System.out.print(enterkey);


    enterkey = readinput.nextLine();
     System.out.print(enterkey);

    if(enterkey == ""){

        System.out.println("It works!");
```

Thanks

-- edit --
the following code works using the `equals` method for the string instead of `==`

```
    Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String enterkey = "Hola";
    System.out.print(enterkey);


    enterkey = readinput.nextLine();
     System.out.print(enterkey);

    if(enterkey.equals("")){

        System.out.println("It works!");
```

how can this be done, and what are the pros to doing this using the buffered input reader?

Comment: Compare `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with `==`, which compares two object references to determine if they refer to the same object.

Comment: First of all, never compare Strings with == in Java.

Comment: Thanks, 'compare strings using the equals method'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works using java.util.Scanner and will take multiple "enter" keystrokes:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String readString = scanner.nextLine();
    while(readString!=null) {
        System.out.println(readString);

        if (readString.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Read Enter Key.");
        }

        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            readString = scanner.nextLine();
        } else {
            readString = null;
        }
    }
```

To break it down:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readString = scanner.nextLine();
```

These lines initialize a new `Scanner` that is reading from the [standard input stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) (the keyboard) and reads a single line from it.

```
    while(readString!=null) {
        System.out.println(readString);
```

While the scanner is still returning non-null data, print each line to the screen.

```
        if (readString.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Read Enter Key.");
        }
```

If the "enter" (or return, or whatever) key is supplied by the input, the `nextLine()` method will return an empty string; by checking to see if the string is empty, we can determine whether that key was pressed.  Here the text **Read Enter Key** is printed, but you could perform whatever action you want here.

```
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            readString = scanner.nextLine();
        } else {
            readString = null;
        }
```

Finally, after printing the content and/or doing something when the "enter" key is pressed, we check to see if the scanner has another line; for the standard input stream, this method will "block" until either the stream is closed, the execution of the program ends, or further input is supplied.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        Double d = scan.nextDouble();


        String newStr = "";
        Scanner charScanner = new Scanner( System.in ).useDelimiter( "(\\b|\\B)" ) ;
        while( charScanner.hasNext() ) { 
            String  c = charScanner.next();

            if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("\r")) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                newStr += c;    
            }
        }

        System.out.println("String: " + newStr);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
```

This code works fine