# (Java) Switch/Case With Enter

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I need help with switch, here is my part of my code that I need help with.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
do
    {
        System.out.println("\nAt each turn, type: ");
        System.out.println("P to print");
        System.out.println("M to mix (shuffle the cards)");
        System.out.println("S to save");
        System.out.println("Q to quit");
        System.out.println("Just ENTER to play a turn");

        meun = kb.nextLine();


        switch (meun)
        {
            case ("P"):
            case ("p"):     System.out.println("\nPlayer1 cards: " + p1.toString());
//More Codes...
            case (//Would like to have an ENTER here.):
```

How do I just get an "enter" in the next case after P. What I want is that if the user just hit enter then the program will play another turn. I was thinking about doing `String.valueOf(kb.nextLine())` but that does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you tried with ASCII value (13) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you should check for en **empty string** since, *Just enter* will actually return an empty string to `Scanner.nextLine()`.

```
    switch (meun)
    {
    case "":
         // Next turn.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use an empty string, like:

```
case "" : System.out.println("Blah, blah, blah...");
```

Or change "" to KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER or just 13 should work.
And change the input from a String to a char.

Answer (score 1):

For console input, hitting enter sends your command to standard input and is also not a character that you could put in a `switch`. For your situation it's probably easiest to use another character like `t` to play a turn.

If you were to implement a [key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) it would be possible to detect the enter key as an input, but that seems like it would be overkill for your program's needs.

EDIT: the other answerers have helpfully provided much more useful answers!

Comment: I wish that were the case. But for this program, my professor wants us to implement an enter key.

Comment: Perhaps try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281543/java-using-scanner-enter-key-pressed).