# Java Wait for Enter press (do not execute multiple keypresses)

Tags: java

I have a procedural Java Program that has multiple segments that I would like to execute manually (using "Press Enter to Proceed").

Right now I've been trying with System.in.read() or Scanner but if I would make multiple enter presses, it automatically executes the next segment.

how might I regulate this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281543/java-using-scanner-enter-key-pressed?rq=1

Comment: Can you empty the input buffer after each segment has completed?  I've not tried it, but does something like [pseudo code] System.in.read([byte array of in.available() length]); to "flush" everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `BufferedReader` instead of `System.in.read()` . It has a built-in flush mechanism too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove everything from the InputStream before you wait for the next enter.

`System.in.available()` returns the number of bytes currently in the stream.

```
System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()]);
```

This clears the Stream, so now the user has to enter something again.

Note: `System.in.skip()` doesn't work for some reason.